# Pywinauto can't to move a File Explorer and change this window

Tags: pywinauto

everyone

I'm trying to move a File Explorer  and change this window

```
file_explorer = r'C:\Windows\explorer.exe'
os.startfile(file_explorer)
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="File Explorer", timeout=5)

window = app.window(title="File Explorer")
window.draw_outline()
window.move_window(x=20, y=20, width=60, height=100, repaint=True)
```

But this code ot work

```
AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'move_window' were found (typo?)
```

Winodows 10

Can you help me please in this problem?
Thanks for your all ansvers

Answer (score 0):

I found a decigion in this my problem
backend="uia" - need remove, because "uia" haven't a move_window metod
I hope,this my experience will be helpfull in your work.

app = Application().connect(title="File Explorer", timeout=5) - worked